# Django 1.11 admin Invalid field name(s) given in select_related

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django Admin documentation about [select related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related), the code example specifies that declaration of `list_select_related = ('authors', )` will help to prevent N+1 issues.

I am attempting to use this with a set of models as defined below:

```
class Grouping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)

class InsightCondition(models.Model):
    criterion = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)


class Insight(models.Model):
    my_other_thing = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    grouping = models.ForeignKey('Grouping', related_name="insights",  blank=False, null=False)
    condition = models.ForeignKey('InsightCondition', related_name='insights', null=True, blank=True)
```

When attempting to use the Django admin declrations, I still see the n+1 issue in the log. In order to fix this, I add the `list_select_related = ('insights', )` to the following class:

```
@admin.register(Insight)
class InsightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('condition_link', 'uid', 'grouping_link',
                'detail_description', 'state', )
    list_filter = ('grouping', 'condition')
    list_select_related = ('grouping', 'condition')

    grouping_link = easy.ForeignKeyAdminField('grouping')
    condition_link = easy.ForeignKeyAdminField('condition')

    pass


@admin.register(Grouping)
class GroupingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'insight_count')
    search_fields = ['name', 'insights__uid']
    list_select_related = ('insights', ) 

    def insight_count(self, group):
        return group.insights.count()
    pass

@admin.register(InsightCondition)
class InsightConditionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('criterion', 'description', ) 
    search_fields = ('criterion', 'description', )

    # Failing Lines .... 
    list_select_related = (
         'insights',
    )    
    select_related = ('insights', )
    pass
```

When loading on the admin site, I get the error

```
FieldError at /admin/insights/insightcondition/
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'insights'. Choices are: (none)
```

Full error at http://dpaste.com/1YJX3VK

I thought about the possibility of this being an issue with the installed packages so I have included those below:

```
bleach (2.0.0)
coverage (4.4.1)
decorator (4.1.1)
Django (1.11.2)
django-admin-easy (0.3.2)
django-debug-toolbar (1.8)
django-extensions (1.8.1)
django-fsm (2.6.0)
django-reversion (2.0.9)
djangorestframework (3.6.3)
entrypoints (0.2.3)
honeybadger (0.0.6)
html5lib (0.999999999)
ipykernel (4.6.1)
ipython (6.1.0)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
ipywidgets (6.0.0)
jedi (0.10.2)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.1.0)
jupyter-console (5.1.0)
jupyter-core (4.3.0)
lxml (3.8.0)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
mistune (0.7.4)
nbconvert (5.2.1)
nbformat (4.3.0)
newrelic (2.88.1.73)
notebook (5.0.0)
pandocfilters (1.4.1)
pexpect (4.2.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
pip (9.0.1)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.14)
psutil (5.2.2)
ptyprocess (0.5.2)
pyaml (16.12.2)
Pygments (2.2.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.2)
PyYAML (3.12)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
qtconsole (4.3.0)
setuptools (36.2.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.10.0)
sqlparse (0.2.3)
tblib (1.3.2)
terminado (0.6)
testpath (0.3.1)
tornado (4.5.1)
traitlets (4.3.2)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
webencodings (0.5.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
widgetsnbextension (2.0.0)
```

Any help would be appreciated as the N+1 is murder on the database as well as load times. I'm assuming that I have done something stupid or overlooked something that should be obvious.

Comment: Why is there select_related in InsightConditionAdmin when there already is list_select_related declared?

Comment: I have removed the `select_related` and there has been no change. According to how I have read the documentation, The `select_related` is legal to have even if there is a `list_select_related` declared. You can also declare `list_select_related = True` and specify `select_related` for more control according to the documentation.